# question about norms of linear maps

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $A = (a_{ij})$, $1 \leq i \leq m$, $1 \leq j \leq n$ is an $m \times n$ matrix. then $A: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ given by

$$ A(x) = A(x_1,...,x_n) = ( \sum_{j=1}^n a_{1j}x_j, ..., \sum_{j=1}^n a_{mj}x_j ) $$ then we have

$$ ||A(x)||_{\infty} \leq C ||x||_{\infty}$$

where $C = \max\{ \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}| : 1 \leq j \leq m \} $

What is the meaning of $||A(x)||$ ??? I am kind of confused about. Help would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: If you apply a matrix $A$ to a vector $x$ you will get another vector, say $y$. Notice that, there are different norms, what you have is the infinite norm which you may not be  familiar with. However, you must be familiar with the Eucleadian norm $||Ax||_2=||y||_2$.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. I have posted my attempt to the question: Can you tell me if I have done it correctly ? thanks

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\|A(x)\|_\infty$ is the maximum absolute value of the entries of $A(x)$.

That is, noting that
$$
A(x) = ( \sum_{j=1}^n a_{1j}x_j, ..., \sum_{j=1}^n a_{mj}x_j )
$$
We have
$$
\|A(x)\|_\infty = \max_{1 \leq k \leq m} \left|\sum_{j=1}^n a_{kj}x_j\right|
$$

Comment: thanks you very much. I have posted my attempt as an answer. Can you tell me if it is correct?

Answer (score 0):

MY attempt:

Select $l$ such that $1 \leq l \leq k$ with $||A(x)|| = \left| \sum_{j=1}^n a_{lj} x_l \right| $

$$ \therefore \left| \sum_{j=1}^n a_{lj} x_l \right| = \left| \sum_{j=1}^n a_{lj} \right| \left|x_l \right| \leq \max_{1 \leq i \leq m} \{ \left| \sum_{j=1}^n a_{lj} \right| \} |x_l| \leq C ||x||_{\infty}$$

since $|x_l| \leq \max\{ |x_i| : 1 \leq i \leq n \} = ||x||_{\infty}$

Comment: Perfect! well done.